# Telerik RadHtmlChart not a known element

Tags: vb.net

I have Telerik bar chart  code that I want to embed on my Visual Basic page 
However  RadHtmlChart and it's sub-components are not known.How do I make telerik RadHtmlChart  work within VB page.If there is any other tool that I can use to embed bar graph,suggestions are welcome.

```
             <form id="form1" runat="server">

                 <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    <Scripts>
                        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
                    </Scripts>
                </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 //Put your JavaScript code here.
                </script>



                <div id="content-container">
                    <div id="content">
            <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server"> 

            <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" Width="800px"             
            </telerik:RadHtmlChart>                              
          </div>
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok thanks I tried to modify it i hope it makes sense now?